# How to override BouncyCastle method that throws exception on cert expiration?

Tags: java, certificate, bouncycastle

I am using certs to sign a request body and to verify it. I have a use case where the verification might be asked for after the cert used for signing it (signed using private key) has expired. I want to continue validating the signature and proceed with other checks even if the cert has expired.

The problem is BouncyCastle (thats what I am using underneath) throws CertPathValidatorException exception when trying to validate using expired cert.

The #PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate throws CertPathValidatorException as one of the first exceptions. Meaning, even if I override this method and ignore this exception, it will omit the following checks.

Most methods called from this method are protected and cannot be accessed directly from outside world, so if I have to use them I will have to duplicate quite some code from BouncyCastle. Other way is to use reflection, but I would not want to do that.

Are there any other suggestions/ options?

Comment: Use [`PKIXParameters.setDate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/PKIXParameters.html#setDate-java.util.Date-)

Comment: Timestamping (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3161) is the mechanism to keep signatures valid after the signature cert is expired. But if the signatures have been made without timestamps in the past the suggestion of @JamesKPolk is the way to go. Before validation set the date to `CertificateNotAfter-1Day` and after validation to `null` to reset the behavior.